# How do you prove that a quadrilateral is a parallelogram using vectors?

Tags: vectors

> PQRS is a quadrilateral where A, B, C, and D are the midpoints of SP, PQ, QR, and RS, respectively. Prove using vector methods that ABCD is a parallelogram.

I am unsure how I can prove it is a parallelogram with only this information. Thanks.

Comment: You mean "ABCD"?

Comment: @deepak, A, B, C, and D are the midpoints of the PQRS quadrilateral

Comment: Yes, I understand fine. I meant your typo in the question. Please edit.

Comment: Deepak is pointing out that you said "$\color{red}{ABC}$ is a parallelogram."  First thing to ask yourself is, how would you prove a quadrilateral is a parallelogram without using vectors?

Comment: @deepak thank you for pointing out the mistake!

Comment: @saulspatz haha good question perhaps angles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outline.

Assign position vectors (relative to some arbitrary origin $O$ which you don't have to characterise further) to $P, Q, R, S$. For example for $P$, you can call it $\mathbb{p}$.

Note that the midpoint of points $M$ (position vector $\mathbb{m}$) and $N$ (position vector $\mathbb{n}$) has the position vector $\frac 12 (\mathbb{m} + \mathbb{n})$.

Use that to find the vectors for the four sides of $ABCD$ by vector subtraction.

Now use the property that in a parallelogram, the parallel sides have vectors of the same magnitude and either the same or the exact opposite direction (depending on how you take the order of the points). In vector algebra terms, this would be represented by $\mathbb{u} = \pm \mathbb{v}$. Show this for both sets of parallel sides and hence complete the proof.